Kotlin serialization ignoring field
I am trying to combine kotlinx.serialization with Atlas Device SDKs. My idea is that I will have one field serialized with kotlin (type) and second field will be saved into DB with Atlas SDK (_type). So in setter of type I will always set value into _type.
But when I try to test serialization, it looks like _type is not set correctly. Can deserialization ignore type setter?
Test
@Test
fun testClassTest() {
    val dialogValue = TestClass(type = HeaderDialogValueType.DECIMAL_NUMBER)
    val dialogValueString = KotlinUtils.json.encodeToString(dialogValue)
    println(dialogValueString)
    val dialogValue2 = KotlinUtils.json.decodeFromString<HeaderDialogValue>(dialogValueString)

    assert(dialogValue.type == dialogValue2.type)
}

Class I want to serialize and save with Atlas SDK
@Serializable
class TestClass() {
    @Transient
    private var _type: String = HeaderDialogValueType.TEXT.name

    var type: HeaderDialogValueType = HeaderDialogValueType.TEXT
        get() {
            return HeaderDialogValueType.valueOf(_type)
        }
        set(value) {
            field = value
            _type = value.name
        }

    constructor(type: HeaderDialogValueType) : this() {
        this.type = type
    }
}

Enum class
@Serializable
enum class HeaderDialogValueType {
    @SerialName("NUMBER")
    NUMBER,
    @SerialName("TEXT")
    TEXT,
    @SerialName("ROLL")
    ROLL,
    @SerialName("DECIMAL_NUMBER")
    DECIMAL_NUMBER
}


Have you attempted to serialize and deserialize your class?

@SimonJacobs Thanks for anwer. What exactly do you mean? Test in my question is testing serialization and deserealization of my class

Since you can run almost any code without breaking anything, normally the best way to figure out if something works is to first try it. Therefore I suggest you try serializing and deserializing your class to see how the library behaves. You will learn more about the library and you will probably be pleased with the results.

Make sure you imported Transient annotation from the right package:

import kotlinx.serialization.Transient

I assume KotlinUtils.json is kotlinx.serialization.json.Json. If it's GSON you may need to use @Expose(serialize = false).
Also, is decodeFromString<HeaderDialogValue>(...) supposed to be decodeFromString<TestClass>(...)?
